# Running webdriver IEDriver on Jenkins fails

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have a small C# webdriver test suite dll which I recently created...

- Runs fine in Visual Studio
- Runs from the command line perfectly using the NUnit 3 console runner.

I have Jenkins installed on my laptop (for testing before I put it into my live Jenkins), running with my Windows credentials. When I execute the test suite using the same NUnit3 console runner command I used before, all the tests fail, can't even log in as it can't find any elements. I took screenshots with Selenium & it's just a black rectangle!

Anyone have any ideas on how to get IE behaving - I bet it's a Windows permissions thing from Jenkins. Thanks!

Comment: Is Jenkins running as a service under the local system account ?

Comment: No - I'm running it under my credentials, which makes it even stranger to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.

Turns out you can't do what I'm attempting - it's a known issue with the way IE is built. What I had to do is install a new Jenkins node on another machine and get that to run the IE tests. That way it did work.